# How can I access MariaDb outside from Helm installation

Tags: kubernetes, mariadb, kubernetes-helm, rke

I have a RKE2 kube installation, 3 nodes, I install MariaDB from BitNami repository:

```
- name: mariadb
  repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
  version: 10.3.2
```

It boots up correctly in my kube installation, but I need to access it from outside the cluster, let's say with my Navicat client as example.

This is my **values.yaml**:

```
mariadb:
  clusterDomain: a4b-kube.local
  auth:
    rootPassword: "password"
    replicationPassword: "password"
  architecture: replication
  primary:
    service:
      type: LoadBalancer
      loadBalancerIP: mariadb.acme.com
  secondary:
    replicaCount: 2
```

Listing the services I see:

```
NAME                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
a4b-test-mariadb-primary     LoadBalancer   10.43.171.45   <pending>     3306:31379/TCP   48m
```

And the external IP never gets updated, I also try specifing an IP instead of dns, in my case was 192.168.113.120 but I got same result. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you confirm how you're running the cluster? Kind, minikube, AKS, GKE, etc?

Comment: I'm sorry you right I'm gonna update the question, it is RKE2 1.22.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might consider using NodePort

```
mariadb:
  clusterDomain: a4b-kube.local
  auth:
    rootPassword: "password"
    replicationPassword: "password"
  architecture: replication
  primary:
    service:
      type: NodePort
      nodePort: 32036
  secondary:
    replicaCount: 2
```

`nodePort: 32036` you can choose in range 30000 - 32767 (default)
Then, you can access via `nodeIP:nodePort`

Answer (score 1):

You need an ingress controller to setup the EXTERNAL-IP. But if you have no intention to expose the database to the Internet; and the cluster nodes are network reachable to your client application, you can use `NodePort` instead of `LoadBalancer`. You can then connect to your database thru any of the 3 nodes with the node port from the outside of your cluster.